# Making one variable be shapes of different colors (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2

So right now I've got this plot:

[my plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Fs3c.png)

(sorry it's not inline image, this is my first time on Stack Overflow and it wouldn't let me post images)

The plot is produced with this code:

```
ggplot(potassium.data,             
aes(x=Experiment,y=value, 
colour=Pedigree))+geom_jitter()+labs(title=element)
```

The problem is, there are 31 different maize pedigrees being plotted here, so it's difficult to distinguish the colors from each other. I was wondering if it's possible to make it so that the color and shape of the point are used to uniquely identify a pedigree, so that for example one pedigree is red squares, another is red circles, a third one is blue squares, a fourth is blue circles, and so on. This would make it far easier to distinguish the points. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Try adding `shape = Pedigree`, but frankly I think your idea will just make your graph _less_ readable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think thats possible, if you do the shaping by pedigree you will just end up with as many categories of shapes as you have colors now.

geom_label() and geom_text() would let you plot the cultivar id directly onto the plot, then maybe you could build a separate column for something equivalent to genus, so that the cultivars could be grouped somehow (maybe A, B, PH, etc). Then you could color by that "genus" column, which would make the plot look better:

```
ggplot(potassium.data,             
aes(x=Experiment,y=value, label=Pedigree, colour = genus))+
geom_label(position = position_jitter())+
labs(title=element)
```

Ideally you would end up with a plot colored by the genus while only plotting the suffix digits currently in Pedigree.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree with Nathan and Joran, the plot is quite confusing by having so many different points and adding shapes into the mix is unlikely to help.

To answer your question you should be able to use shape=pedigree, but maybe to make the graph more readable you could join the pedigrees from one experiment to the other with a geom_line so the reader spends less time scanning.